# How to augment a global variable type with static methods

Tags: typescript

I would like to augment the `URLSearchParams` type and add a static function (`fromObject`).
I have this code which is erroring out (see [fiddle](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=5&pc=2#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwAdYBnEAeQCMArcDACh2oC55GbMBKFgJXBxmAAeYhhhZUAcwA08EWMkA%20ANwAoFQFVuAGQDKIWGAAWABVhQAtsQB0iGDnOV2GeAF4kaTLnwNmrarS54TV19GCNTGAtieABvFXgE%20DgMZBh8VBAAdyDtPQMTM0s6IhhSR1ofKg4OVQBfIA)):

```js
declare function parseObject(obj: object): Record<string, string>;

// ERROR: Property 'fromObject' does not exist on type '{ new (init?: string | Record<string, string> | string[][] | URLSearchParams | undefined): URLSearchParams; prototype: URLSearchParams; toString(): string; }'.(2339)
URLSearchParams.fromObject = function (obj: object): URLSearchParams {
    return new URLSearchParams(parseObject(obj));
}
```

---

I've tried to redeclare `URLSearchParams` this way (see [fiddle](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=8&ssc=3&pln=3&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwAdYBnEAeQCMArcDACh2oC55GbMBKFgJXBxmAAeYhhhZUAcwA08EWMkA%20ANwAoFaEiwEAN1jwAqtwAyAZRCwwACwAKsKAFtiLAN4r47%20KhAB3OuKwYAPwscuIS8AA%20sqJhANoAugmR8Lxg-EKhkjKZEgrJhqbmMFa2MA7EyWigiOIgwFwGxmYWNnaOqh6EMDgYPQCeBCAsBc3FrWXtbh69JjGSdA05HR6I3faU7PRsLGy0DSNFJW3EqgC%20qioHLaXlAHSrOOvUtPAAvEhomLj4DMysz5xhk1DuNyvBXJ04BhkDB8F5vI1CtdjnQiDBSBtaL8qBwOGc1EA)):

```js
declare var URLSearchParams: {
    new(init?: string | string[][] | Record<string, string> | URLSearchParams | undefined): URLSearchParams;
    prototype: URLSearchParams;
    toString(): string;
    fromObject(obj: object): URLSearchParams;
};
```

but getting the following error:

> Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '`URLSearchParams`' must be of type '`{ new (init?: string | Record<string, string> | URLSearchParams | string[][] | undefined): URLSearchParams; prototype: URLSearchParams; toString(): string; }`', but here has type '`{ new (init?: string | Record<string, string> | URLSearchParams | string[][] | undefined): URLSearchParams; prototype: URLSearchParams; toString(): string; fromObject(obj: object): URLSearchParams; }`'.(2403)
>   input.ts(14, 1): 'URLSearchParams' was also declared here.

It of course does not add the `URLSearchParams.fromObject` definition.

---

I tried to augment it as an interface (see [fiddle](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwAdYBnEAeQCMArcDACh2oC55GbMBKFgJXBxmAAeYhhhZUAcwA08EWMkA+ANwAoFeIwgYiKGAQBVbgBkAyiFhgAFgAVYUALbF4AbxXx3SGDnuV29NixstFzwhqbmMFa2MA7EqgC+qiphZhY2do4AdIhePtS08AC8SGiYuPgMzKz5nCwpEVEZTq4e8HAYyDD4qCAA7qHGqZHpMY50RDCkvrSVVBwcCWpgeCLwAB5F8D399WnRsXQLKmvZudOY8AD0l-CCALR38FDIEvYgqJrAQA)):

```js
interface URLSearchParams {
    fromObject(obj: object): URLSearchParams;
};
```

but that augments the instance interface, not the type (constructor):

```js
const x = new URLSearchParams();
x.fromObject // <-- augmented
```

---

I tried to augment the constructor this way (see [fiddle](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=3&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=2#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwAdYBnEAeQCMArcDACh2oC55GbMBKFgJXBxmAAeYhhhZUAcwA08EWMkA%20ANwAoFRgCeBBAFVuAGQDKIWGAAWABVhQAtsQDCeOckz94AXnibtORPD1GJjDmVjC2xKoq4hggMIhQYLoGxqaW1naOqM6uMPAA3irwRUgwODaU7PRsLGy0XP7JQSHpESoAvmoBKcFpYXYAdIil5dS0HkhomLj4DMyso5wsXU294fmFxXAYyDD4qCAA7g2BqaHhdEQwpBW0s1QcHKodQA)):

```js
type URLSearchParamsConstructor = typeof URLSearchParams;

interface URLSearchParamsConstructor {
    fromObject(obj: object): URLSearchParams;
}
```

but getting the following errors on both the type and the interface:

> Duplicate identifier 'URLSearchParamsConstructor'.(2300)

---

fyi, the `URLSearchParams` type is [defined in `lib.dom.d.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/712967b2780e8ecd28f8f1e2e89c1ebd2592bb4c/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L16156) as:

```js
declare var URLSearchParams: {
    prototype: URLSearchParams;
    new(init?: string[][] | Record<string, string> | string | URLSearchParams): URLSearchParams;
    toString(): string;
};
```

I'm looking for any suggestion on this.

Comment: Your choices as I see them: modify your copy of `lib.dom.d.ts`; use a new variable instead of `URLSeachParams` for this; use control flow analysis to narrow the type of `URLSearchParams` to one with the extra property, but this will only work inside the immediate scope where you want to call it.  Modifying the library is probably the least hacky way of doing this.  Let me know if you want me to write up an answer.

Comment: thanks @jcalz, but I would hope there mat be a better, TypeScripty way of doing it, before I create an issue with TypeScript/lib.dom. I'm sure there are other cases that would require this, e.g. augmenting 3rd party libs

Comment: There isn't a better way without adding a feature like [micrsoft/TypeScript#4062](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4062) to the language.  I will probably write up an answer anyway when time allows, unless someone else gets here first (and they should feel free to do it if so)